# Prevent Multiprocess from using all memory

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing

I am making a multiprocess for a password cracker and the last time I ran it my computer literally died. Is there any way I can prevent that from happening? I amount of memory it used reached 100% and my computer froze up. I need to run multiple processes to allow different programs to test part of the guesses at a time. This would work if I had more memory, but if anyone has any solutions, please say so.

```
import hashlib
import itertools
import time
flag2=0
def getpass(comb, usechar, pass_hash):
global flag2
st = time.time()
for guess in comb:
    guess = ''.join(guess)
    digest = hashlib.md5(guess.encode('utf-8').strip()).hexdigest()
    if digest == pass_hash:
        print("password is: " + guess)
        flag2=1
        print("Time Completed(seconds): " + str(time.time() - st))
        break;
    if flag2==1:
        break;
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from multiprocessing import Process
    flag = 0
    lower = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    upper = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    nums = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    char = ["~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "[", "]", "{", "}", ":", ";", "\'", "\"", "\\", "|", ",", ".", "<", ">", "?", "/"]
    pass_hash = input("Enter md5 hash: ")
    #a=all, l=letters, n=numbers
    pass_type = input(str("Enter Password Type: "))
    usechar = []

processes = []




if pass_type == "a":
    usechar = nums + lower + upper + char
elif pass_type == "l":
    usechar = lower + upper
elif pass_type == "n":
    usechar = nums
else:
    usechar = nums + lower + upper + char
try:
    pass_file = open("Passwords.txt", "r")
    print("Accessing Passwords")
except:
    print("No file found")
    quit()
st = time.time()
for word in pass_file:
    enc_word = word.encode('utf-8')
    digest = hashlib.md5(enc_word.strip()).hexdigest()
    
    if digest == pass_hash:
        print("Password found")
        print("Password is " + word)
        print("Time Completed(seconds): " + str(time.time() - st))
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 0:
    
    
    
    print("Password is not in the list. Using brute-force")
    
    for password_length in range(1, 20):
        processes = []
        comb = itertools.product(usechar, repeat=password_length)
        thr = 0
        leng = 0
        for i in range(1,20):
            leng += len(usechar)^i
        for i in range(0,2):
            processes.append(Process(target=getpass, args=[list(comb)[thr:round(leng/2)+thr], usechar, pass_hash]))
            thr+=round(leng/2)
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
    if flag2==0:
        print("password is over 20 characters long")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, the variable `comb` is an extraordinarily long list, and you are passing pieces of this extraordinarily long to each of your subprocesses.  This is probably where all of your memory is going.

It would probably be smarter to use a thread pool of some size, and create multiple pieces of work based on the first two letters of the text.  Then each worker would generate all the passwords with those first two letters (as a generator, not as a fully fleshed out list) and see what they find.  You will find you don't need much memory at all.

Here is a brief outline, breaking up only on the first character.

```
def worker(start_character):
    for length in range(1, max_length):
        for password_suffix in itertools.product(usechar, length - 1)
            password = start_character + password_suffix
            ......
        

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(cracker, usechar)
```

Each thread uses virtually no memory at all.  You can use as many threads as your machine has CPUs.

Comment: When you use the map, by cracker do you mean worker?

Comment: Yes.  I was naming my workers "cracker".  Since they were cracking passwords.

Comment: What exactly does pool.map do? Does it allow the workers to give the main script values?

Comment: pool.map creates multiple threads, calling `cracker` on each of the items in the list `usechar`.  It is a pool of threads and limits the number of threads to the number of cpu's.  As each piece is finished, it sends the thread the next piece.